# Animation is not working the first time

Tags: android, animation

**FIRST:** I do have tried all stuff I've found on the internet, Stackoverflow too. So dont put it as duplicated, because nothing works!

I do have an expandable Recyclerview as you can see, the animation does not work on the first time. At the second time it works perfectly.

```html
        cardview_sehr_wichtig.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (counter_sehr_wichtig){
                    case 0:
                        notiz_anzahl_sehr_wichtig.animate()
                                .rotation(360);
                        recycler_view_sehr_wichtig.animate()
                                .translationY(-recycler_view_sehr_wichtig.getHeight())
                                .alpha(0.f)
                                .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                        recycler_view_sehr_wichtig.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                                    }
                                })
                                .setDuration(500);

                                counter_sehr_wichtig = 1;
                        break;
```

[Problem animation gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nII5f.gif)

Comment: Before you start animation check if animation running, and if not, start animation.

Comment: How can I check it then?

Comment: Try like this: `notiz_anzahl_sehr_wichtig.hasEnded()`.